# Why am I keep getting this error while executing mongod command on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Ive been stuck to this error since two weeks please someone help me out.
I am running intel processor mac catalina with mongodb version5.0

The error is something related to, asio.system","value":22

[image: 1]

> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.145-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.152-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.152-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.152-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.154-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":7191,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/System/Volumes/Data/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"karanpun"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.14","gitVersion":"1b3b0073a0b436a8a502b612f24fb2bd572772e5","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"19.6.0"}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.155-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"/System/Volumes/Data/data/db"}}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.156-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.172-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=1536M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.853-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"WiredTiger version file is empty"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.856-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1672019727:856423][7191:0x1197eedc0], connection: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 808: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000013: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.878-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"WiredTiger version file is empty"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.885-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1672019727:885549][7191:0x1197eedc0], connection: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 808: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000013: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.890-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"WiredTiger version file is empty"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.897-05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error","attr":{"error":13,"message":"[1672019727:897060][7191:0x1197eedc0], connection: int __posix_open_file(WT_FILE_SYSTEM *, WT_SESSION *, const char *, WT_FS_OPEN_FILE_TYPE, uint32_t, WT_FILE_HANDLE **), 808: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000013: handle-open: open: Permission denied"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.903-05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.903-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"13: Permission denied"}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.903-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":687}}
> {"t":{"$date":"2022-12-25T20:55:27.903-05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

I have tried changing the data storage directory from mongod.conf file and gave full permission to the user of that directory. Also tried restarting the server after deleting the file mongodb-27017.sock

Answer (score 0):

The error message is specifically complaining about the file '/System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000013'.  The permission denied is coming from the underlying operating system.

Things to check:

- Does the directory '/System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/' exist?
- Does the file '/System/Volumes/Data/data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000013' exist? If it doesn't exist, the error likely occurs while mongod is attempting to create the file.
- Are both the file and directory *owned* by the user running mongod?
- Does the user running mongod have write permission for both the file and directory?
- Is selinux in use on this machine?  If yes, what are the labels for the file/directory?